# Kinesis Freestyle2 brightness keys

Tags: macos, keyboard

I recently connected a Kinesis Freestyle2 Keyboard for Mac to OSX 10.11. All of the media keys work, except for brightness down and brightness up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to the rescue!

While looking through its EventViewer, I noticed that when I pressed the brightness keys, they were being registered as F14 and F15, respectively.

So I added these lines to my [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#privatexml) file:

```
  <item>
    <name>Kinesis Freestyle2</name>
    <appendix>Fix brightness keys</appendix>
    <identifier>kinesis-freestyle2</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F14, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F15, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the SmartSet app and then map your keys of choice to F14 and F15! They also have a preconfigured set for mapping Windows to Opt(Alt) and Alt to Cmd.

Thanks, @scribu, for the tip about F14 and F15!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1014094)

Comment: @Ramhound to clarify, my answer is that you don’t need to use Karabiner. You can use the SmartSet app which is easier to use. I did want to express gratitude for the information about F14 and F15 mapping to the brightness adjustment keys.